# Custom markers with the use of Leaflet

Tags: javascript, api, dictionary, leaflet

I'm trying to use an API which involves Leaflet. The idea is to place points of interests on a map.

In this fiddle you can see what I'm trying to accomplish: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cliff/CRRGC/). The problem I'm facing is that when I'm trying to add a custom icon, the zooming and anchoring fails. For some reason the default icons are placed correctly on the map and I have no idea why those don't fail as well.

All of my code is about the same as the fiddle except for these parts:

Below you can see how I make a custom icon:

```
var waypoint = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'waypoint.png',        
    //iconSize: [30, 30], // size of the icon       
    iconAnchor: [0, 0] // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location      
});
```

And here below you can see how I add the icons in the markers:

```
L.marker(unproject(poi.coord), {
                    title: poi.name,
                    icon: waypoint
                }).addTo(map);
```

Update: Below you can see the difference:

[Image](http://tinypic.com/r/ofattv/5)

What am I missing?

Comment: I've seen your fiddle. Everything looks correct. I've changed the code and added your waypoint as an icon and zooming still works fine.

Comment: Could I be that my Wrapper div or Css is messing with me?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know. For example, as specified in Leaflet documentation, you have to specify the width of the container div explicitly. It could be something like this in your code which conflicts with zooming or anchoring features.

Comment: I tried setting all the css value back to default, still have the same result. I have added an Image in my post, here you can see what goes wrong.

Comment: Do you have any error on your browser console?

Comment: yes i do. i got lots of these Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) https://tiles.guildwars2.com/1/1/0/-4/0.jpg , but i got those errors with the default icons as well.

Comment: This error is not an issue. The 403 means you don't have access to fetch requested image from the server specified. I've tested this case (of course with 404) but the zooming still works. As you have not enough reputation, I can't start chat with you. The number of comments beneath a question has some limitations in StackOVerflow. So I'll try to answer you instead of next comment

Comment: You said you are using **an API which involves Leaflet**. As I've seen in your fiddle, everything is working fine. If you're using a wrapper API, maybe that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: I fixed it. Check my question for my mistake. Thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP.)*

OK, I managed to fix it.

This is what I did wrong, I fetched the external resources ( the .js and .css) and placed them localy im my project. When I added the two in my project with an URL like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.5.1/leaflet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.5.1/leaflet.css" type="text/css">
```

Everything worked as expected.